# How to catch SVG click events that hit the viewbox, rather than elements on it?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an SVG file with various paths, it is embedded into an HTML page using the `object` tag. Javascript is used to provide some interactivity to each path - when it is clicked, a tooltip `rect` is shown. This is what it looks like:

[image: Paths in an SVG file]

I want the tooltip to disappear when someone clicks outside of the path the tooltip is associated with, this is implemented by adding such an event listener to every path:

```
path.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    if (!isTipShown()){
        createTooltip()
    }
    else{
        hideTooltip()
    }
})
```

`isTipShown`, `createTooltip` and `hideTooltip` are functions that check the SVG DOM and modify it accordingly.

This works, but it fails if the click goes to the empty space between the paths themselves - because there is no object to catch it.

**What approach can be chosen to implement such functionality?**

My current thoughts:

- Create a transparent rectangle that covers the entire viewport, and use that as a click target. How would one ensure the rectangle goes to the bottom of everything?
- A click handler for the entire HTML document does the trick, but only if users click outside of the viewport itself.

Comment: You can use click handler for the document and check the event.currentTarget, if the click target is a path, then don't do anything, else hide the tooltip.

Comment: I'd do the rect thing. Not sure what you mean by "goes to the bottom of everything"

Comment: Abhay, the approach you describe works, but it fails when the click goes to the empty space between the paths (because no element receives the click event).

Robert, think of it as layers - the transparent rectangle is placed on top of everything, so all the clicks go to it (rather than the paths below it). You cannot see it, because it is transparent - but it still gets the clicks.

Answer (score 2):

## Tooltip on shapes not my SVG!

How to best remove the tooltip when pressing the svg?
They way i would solve it is:

1. ID on the tooltip.
2. Modify the existing tooltip with the ID.
3. Remove tooltip with ID when pressed anywhere else

By reusing the tooltip, there can only be one tooltip on the page at one time.
Removing the tooltip (not deleting) makes it possible to reuse the same tooltip again when a new path is presed.

Here is an example:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var pathRed = document.getElementById("red");
  var pathOrange = document.getElementById("orange");
  var pathBlue = document.getElementById("blue");
  var paths = [pathRed, pathOrange, pathBlue];

  var toolTip = document.createElement("div");
  toolTip.id = "toolTip";
  var svg = document.getElementById("box");
  var shown = false;

  paths.forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      if (shown == false) {
        toolTip.innerText = element.id;
        toolTip.style.top = (event.pageY) + "px";
        toolTip.style.left = (event.pageX) + "px";
        document.body.appendChild(toolTip);
        shown = true;
        //Only click the path
        event.stopPropagation();
      } else {
        removeToolTip();
      }
    });
  });

  svg.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    removeToolTip();
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  function removeToolTip() {
    shown = false;
    if (document.body.contains(toolTip)) {
      document.body.removeChild(toolTip);
    }
  }

});
```

```css
#toolTip {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #00000099;
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Click the boxes!</h1>
<svg id="box" viewBox="0 0 15 15" width="250px">
  <path id="red" fill="red" d="m0,0 5,0 0,5 -5,0Z"/>
  <path id="orange" fill="orange" d="m5,5 5,0 0,5 -5,0Z"/>
  <path id="blue" fill="blue" d="m10,10 5,0 0,5 -5,0Z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to make sure the rectangle goes below the paths, as if it were a bottom layer.

[SVG does not have a concept of layers](https://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/an-svg-primer), but it can be achieved by making sure that the `rect` is *before* all the elements in the SVG DOM, and all subsequent elements will be placed on top of it, visually:

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" fill="purple"/>
<rect x="20" y="5" width="30" height="30" fill="blue"/>
<rect x="40" y="10" width="30" height="30" fill="green"/>
<rect x="60" y="15" width="30" height="30" fill="yellow"/>
<rect x="80" y="20" width="30" height="30" fill="red"/>
```

[image: Layered squares]

Here is how this was accomplished in practice (the `svgDoc` variable is the root SVG element):

```
    function createBackgroundRectangle(svgDoc){
        var rect = svgDoc.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'rect')
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', 500)
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', 900)
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'id', 'pseudo-background')
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', 0)
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', 0)
        // the opacity is set to 0, so it doesn't get in the way visually. For debugging
        // purposes, you can change it to another value and see the actual rectangle
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'style', 'opacity:0;fill:#ffd42a;fill-opacity:1;')
        svgDoc.rootElement.insertBefore(rect, svgDoc.rootElement.children[0])
    }
```

`svgDoc.rootElement.insertBefore(rect, svgDoc.rootElement.children[0])` makes it the first, as it is inserted before the current child at index 0.